# Autoreply email based on condition

Tags: email, thunderbird, automation

I am looking for a software or an addon for thunderbird which can help to reply or send email automatically based on defined condition.

For example, when I receive an email with content :

```
From : John Lennon<JohnL@gmail.com>
Body : When is your birthday ?
```

Supposed I've already tell the software that if someone send me email which the body contains `When is your birthday` so it will reply automatically :

```
Hi John,
My birthday is on 3rd-Jan
```

Does anything like this exist ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without an addon.

1. Create a template by starting a new message, then use File / Save as Template (this should contain the text you want in the body
2. Create a new Message Filter with the conditions you want - ie, select "Body" from the drop down, and Contains as the condition with the text you want to match
3. In Actions, select "Reply with Template" and choose the template created in step 1.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want ! However, I have some questions : `1. Can I set auto-reply mentions the sender name ?` ,eg : "Hi John" (John is who sent me a message) `2.Messages which auto-replied contains "(was : sender's message subject)", can I omit it ?`, eg : "Hello (was: Dear friend)" (Dear friend is the subject of the message John sent to me). Thanks !

Comment: @ITFan the basic templates in Thunderbird don't give you much control, so you may want to check out the SmartTemplate extension, which lets you control the subject and use %fields% you can populate from the incoming message.